# How to receive dynamic data in Web API controller Post method

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, free-jqgrid

jqgrid posts json data in POST request buffer as

```
{"headerData": {
    "Tasudok": "134",
    "Kuupaev": "2015-11-23",
    "Dokumnr": "135319"
   },


"rowData": {
  "Toode":"",
  "Kogus":"0.0000",
  "Nimetus":"öäölä&lt;a",
  "_rowsum":"0.00",
  "Id":"1639",
  "Dokumnr":"135319",
  "_oper":"edit",
  "_rowid":"1639"
  }
}
```

Data is posted to ASP.NET MVC4 Web API using URL  like `API/Entity/someid?culture=en&layout=1` with default routing.

`headerData` and `rowData` value properties are defined in runtime and can vary.

For example in some call rowData may contain additional properties and some rowData properties may be missing.

`culture` and `layout` query string paramaters are optional.

How to receive parameters in WebAPI controller ?

I tried

```
public class EntityController : APIController
{

public class PostParams {
    public string culture { get; set; }
    public int? layout { get; set; }
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(string id, 
      [FromUri]PostParams optionalParams,
      [FromBody]IList<NameValue> headerData,
      [FromBody]IList<NameValue> rowData )
    { ... }


public class NameValue
{
    public string name, value;
}
}
```

But headerData and rowData are empty. How to get all parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## If the structure of the JSON does not change

Having this will permit you to send the body like the one you provided at a url like
API/Entity/someid?culture=en&layout=1.

**To specify optional query parameter in your controller route, give them a default value like**:

```
public class EntityController : APIController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]string culture="EN", [FromUri]int layout=1, YourBody body )
    { ... }
}
```

If YourBody is always like the one you mentionned, something like this should be deserialized automatically:

```
public class YourBody
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> HeaderData {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string, string> RowData{get; set;}
}
```

and would give you full access to any element of the body.

## If the structure of the JSON can change

Something like this would permit the receive any kind of json:

```
public HttpResponseMessage  Post([FromBody]JToken body)
{
    // Process the body
    return ...
}
```

You will need some extra validation since no object deserialization will be made. The only think you'll know is that your body is a JSON.

You therefore may want to parse it to see if it looks like what you are expecting.
See [that post about how to access element of a JSON with JToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795045/accessing-all-items-in-the-jtoken-json-net).

For instance, you could do something like the following to handle a changing body content and still handle optional query parameters of your route :

```
public HttpResponseMessagePost([FromBody]JToken body, [FromUri]string culture="EN", [FromUri]int layout=1)
{
    JObject headerData= body["headerData"].Value<JObject>();
    JObject headerData= body["rowData"].Value<JObject>();
    return ...;
}
```

You may also read [this](http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api) about other alternatives for posting raw data to a webapi controller.

Comment: First post method signature causes compile error `Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters`

Comment: Your compiler is right ! I'll update my post (I wrote that code in a text editor, no access to VS nor a compiler) And what do you get if you do what the compiler tells you ? Does it compiles ?

Comment: Yes, it compiles then. Great answer and great link, thank you.

Comment: If it does what you wanted, I thank you in advance to mark my answer as accepted. If there is still some issue with my answer let me know and I will update it !

Comment: I tried first signature. Both `headerData` and `rowData` have null values in controller. How to receive values for them ?

Comment: I posted this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943604/how-to-receive-dynamic-objects-in-webapi-controller

Comment: I think I missed public for both members of YourBody. I answered your question at the link you provided. Everything should work fine now !

Comment: I tried but headerData is empty. I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206340/how-to-post-form-data-to- api-controller