# How to receive dynamic data in WebAPI controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

ASP.NET MVC4 WebAPI Post controller receives json data in POST buffer.
Object contains two fixed name properties, headerData and rowData.
They have have variable number of properties like

```
{"headerData": {
    "Tasudok": "134",
    "Kuupaev": "2015-11-23",
    "Dokumnr": "135319"
   },


"rowData": {
  "Toode":"",
  "Kogus":"0.0000",
  "Nimetus":"öäölä&lt;a",
  "_rowsum":"0.00",
  "Id":"1639",
  "Dokumnr":"135319",
  "_oper":"edit",
  "_rowid":"1639"
  }
}
```

For example in some call rowData may contain additional properties and some rowData properties may be missing.
Data is posted to ASP.NET MVC4 Web API using URL  like `API/Entity/someid?culture=en&layout=1` with default routing.

How to receive parameters in WebAPI controller ?

I tried according to [How to receive dynamic data in Web API controller Post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924458/how-to-receive-dynamic-data-in-web-api-controller-post-method)

```
public class EntityController : APIController
{

    public class Body
    {   Dictionary<string, string> headerData { get; set; }
        Dictionary<string, string> rowData { get; set; }
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(string id, Body body,
        [FromUri]string culture = null,
        [FromUri]uint layout = 0
        )
    { ... }
}
```

But body.headerData and body.rowData have are empty. 
How to get values into them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
public class Body
{   
    Dictionary<string, string> headerData { get; set; }
    Dictionary<string, string> rowData { get; set; }
}
```

explicitly mark your class members as public so the deserializer can do its job !

The following should work:

```
public class Body
{   
    public Dictionary<string, string> headerData { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> rowData { get; set; }
}
```

And also, specify that id will come from the url:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Body body,
    [FromUri]string id, 
    [FromUri]string culture = null,
    [FromUri]uint layout = 0
)
```