# how to post form data to API controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Form data is posted using jquery:

```
$.ajax('API/Validate/Customer?column=1&rowid=2&vmnr=3&isik=4',
   {
       data: JSON.stringify({
           headerData: $("#_form").serializeArray()
       }),
       async: false,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       type: "POST"
   });
```

It is received by ASP.NET MVC4 Web API controller Validate:

```
public class ValidateController : ApiController
{
    public class Body
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> headerData { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> rowData { get; set; }
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Validate(
        string id,
        string column,
        string rowid,
        int? vmnr,
        string isik,
        [FromBody] Body body,

        string dok = null,
        string culture = null,
        uint? company = null
       )
    { ...
```

body.headerData value is null in controller.

According to answer in 
[How to receive dynamic data in Web API controller Post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924458/how-to-receive-dynamic-data-in-web-api-controller-post-method)

body.headerData must have form keys.
However, it is empty.

How to get headerData as key, value pairs in controller ?

Chorme developer tools show that proper json is posted in body:

```
{"headerData":[{"name":"Kalktoode","value":"kllöklö"},
               {"name":"Kaal","value":""}
              ]}
```

I tried to remove

```
 public Dictionary<string, string> rowData { get; set; }
```

from class but problem persists.

Comment: you have to add an attribute `[HttpPost]` to the `Validate` method

Comment: I added but problem persists. In referenced answer data is passed in key value pairs without array. Maybe data should serialised not as array? If yes,  how it can serialized like json data in referenced answer ?

Comment: I think your headerData should look like this `{"headerData":[{"Kalktoode":"kllöklö"}, {"Kaal":""}]}` .. without the name, values.

Comment: Should code form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery used to serialize ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your controller does not match with what you are sending

Indeed, your controller will deserialize body like:

```
{
  "headerData": {"someKey":"someValue", "otherKEy":"otherValue"},
  "rowData": {"someKey":"someKey"}
}
```

And it is **not** the structure of the JSON you actually send.
Your controller looks for a body with 2 members **beeing *Dictionnaries*, not *Arrays of key value pair***.

#### If you want your controller to work with Arrays of key value pair

By array of key value, I mean something like:

```
{
  "headerData": [
    {
      "key": "string",
      "value": "string"
    }
  ],
  "rowData": [
    {
      "key": "string",
      "value": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to update your Body object to:

```
  [HttpPost, Route("test")]
  public void Test(Body b)
  {
  }

  public class Body
  {
      public List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> headerData { get; set; }
      public List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> rowData { get; set; }
  }
```