# c#: read value from json using JToken

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json and I want to get a value from a complex object. Here is my json:

```
{
    "a1" : {
        "a2" : {
            "a3" : "desired_value"
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to obtain the value "desired value". I've tried to obtain it with this code:

```
    var token = JToken.Parse(json);
    string value = token.Value<string>("a1.a2.a3");
```

But the `value` string is null. What should I put in the path so I can read this only once, I mean without getting a token and then iterate trough it's childern and so?

Comment: Did you try using JObject ? This link might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795045/accessing-all-items-in-the-jtoken-json-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) in order to select the property using its path and then extract the value from that:

```
string value = token.SelectToken("a1.a2.a3").Value<string>();
```

`SelectToken` will return `null` if the path isn't found, so you might want to guard against that.

[JToken.Value](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Value__1.htm) expects a key to be provided, whereas [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) supports both keys and paths (a key *is* a simple path). You are providing a path where a key is expected, which results in a value not being found.

To demonstrate the difference, you *could* also retrieve the value of `a3` like this:

```
token.SelectToken("a1.a2").Value<string>("a3");
```

I wouldn't recommend doing it this way, but it does show how paths involve traversal but keys are simple indexers.